# how to get value form this data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
{
  "code": 2001,
  "message": "todays usage",
  "results": [
    {
      "date": "2015-03-20",
      "download": 7.063141,
      "mac": "18f46ab79f0d",
      "upload": 16.086909
    }
  ],
  "status": 200
}
```

how to get value of download from this json object ?i want to get the value of **download** and upload.

Comment: `yourVar[0].results[0].upload` OR `yourVar.results[0].upload` Depends if its an object or an array of objects

Comment: `ng-repet="item in yourVar" --> ng-repeat="result in item.results" --> result.upload` OR `ng-repeat="result in yourVar.results" --> result.upload` Depends if its an object or an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: if the above `json` was assigned to a variable called `jsonObject`:

```
var downloadValue = jsonObject.results[0].download;
var uploadValue = jsonObject.results[0].upload;
```